# How to test whether an element is displayed on the page

Tags: ruby, if-statement, rspec, selenium-webdriver

The following code checks whether an element is displayed and if the element is present runs a specific action, else the test continues normally:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
require 'rspec/expectations'


describe "Current Expense" do


  before(:all) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/disappearing_elements"
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
  end

  after(:all) do
    @driver.quit   
  end


  it "Check icon" do
    @driver.get(@base_url)
    if expect(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").displayed?).to be_truthy 
      @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").click
      sleep 2
      puts "element appears"
    else 
      puts "element NOT appears"
    end
  end
end
```

When the element is present, the message appears, but when the element is not present in the page, an error occurs and the `else` block is not executed. What is causing this error?

Comment: Please add the exception you're seeing to your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using `expect` when you should just have the conditional `@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").displayed?`. If the conditional is `true` you will see the expected message; likewise if it evaluates to `false` you will see `"element NOT appears".

As currently constructed, if the `find_element` method returns `false` then the spec should fail. Please post the error or exception you're seeing so that we can know for sure.

On a side note, what you have right now is fine for a quick and dirty test of whether or not the page is functioning correctly, but you'll probably want to give two cases in your test file:  one where you know the icon will be on the page, and one where it shouldn't be on the page, and then test the outcome for each. For example:

```
#Code omitted
it "has the icon when x is the case" do
  # make x be the case
  @driver.get(@base_url)
  @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").displayed?
  @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").click
  sleep 2
  # code that verifies that the element is on the page
end

it "doesn't have the icon when y is the case" do
  # make y be the case
  @driver.get(@base_url)
  expect { 
   @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").displayed? 
  }.to be_false
end
#code omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

`expect` is the reason for test failure. Find the below snippet for solution.. Cheers!

```
it "has the icon when x is the case" do
  @driver.get(@base_url)
  begin
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']")
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']").click
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    raise 'The Element ' + what + ' is not available'
  end
end

it "doesn't have the icon when y is the case" do
  @driver.get(@base_url)
  begin
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@href='/gallery/']")
    raise 'The Element ' + what + ' is available'
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    expect(true).to be_truthy
  end
end
```