# Ruby Selenium WebDriver: .displayed? method not working

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am trying to run a script where I open a web page and look for a specific element. If the element is present I would like to put 'Element Found', if the element is not present put 'Not Found'. I always get the error **'Unable to locate element'**

I've tried to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639550/how-to-test-whether-an-element-is-displayed-on-the-page/37967721#37967721) but it is still not working. I think this is something relatively easy, but I really don't get what I'm doing wrong:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5
driver.get 'http://www.example.com'

case driver.find_element(:class_name,'example').displayed?
when true
    puts 'ELEMENT FOUND'
when false
    puts 'NOT FOUND'
end
```

with `if` statement:

```
#the rest is identical as in the above example
if (driver.find_element(:class_name,'example').displayed?)
    puts 'ELEMENT FOUND'
else
    puts 'NOT FOUND'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `element` cannot be found, so `.displayed` cannot be determined. `.displayed` can only be called on an element that exists and has **already been found**.

If you want to check `existence` of `element`, you should try as below :-

```
if (driver.find_elements(:class_name,'example').size > 0)
puts 'ELEMENT FOUND'
else
puts 'NOT FOUND'
end
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thanks! it's exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @Acolli you are welcome..please have a look http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work